# Program getting stalled

Tags: c, performance

I have a simple c program that takes in two integers, gives the average, and checks whether or not they're prime. When I run it and give the user input, the program gets stalled, and it doesn't do anything until I hit esc. Once I hit esc, it gives me the correct results. Is this a problem with the server or my code?

Here's my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include "prime.h"
  3 
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6         int x, y;
  7         float avg;
  8 
  9         /* Get integers x and y from user */
 10         printf("Please enter two positive integers\n");
 11         scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
 12         scanf("%d", &x, &y);
 13         printf("You typed in %d and %d\n", x, y);
 14         avg = (x+y)/2;
 15         printf("The average is: %f\n", avg);
 16 
 17       /* Test if x and y are prime */
 18          if(prime(x) == 1)
 19              printf("%d is prime\n", x);
 20          else
 21              printf("%d is not prime\n", x);
 22          if(prime(y) == 1)
 23              printf("%d is prime\n", y);
 24          else
 25              printf("%d is not prime\n", y);
 26 
 27         return 0;
 28 }
```

---

prime.c :

```
     1 #include "prime.h"
  2 
  3 int prime(int x)
  4 {
  5     int isprime;
  6     int i;
  7 
  8     for(i = sqrt(x); i > 1; i--)
  9         {
 10             if(x % i == 0)
 11 
 12             /* isprime is false*/
 13                 isprime = 0;
 14             else{
 15 
 16             /* isprime is true*/
 17                 isprime = 1;
 18                 }
 19             }
 20    return isprime;
 21 }
```

~

Thank you!!

Comment: Line 12, `scanf("%d", &x, &y);` is unnecessary and incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra scanf on line 12, get rid of it:

```
12    //scanf("%d", &x, &y);
```

That is the reason you have to hit escape or enter again.

On top of that, you have an error in your prime logic, anything not divisible by two will be called prime because of line 17:

```
isprime = 1;
```

This says that the value isprime, even if you have found another number that is divisible. So if you imagine going through the number 15, it'll find i = 5 and say isprime = 0; But then it'll get to 2 and say isprime = 1; Not good.

To fix that, add a break after isprime = 0; like this:

```
isprime = 0;
break;
```

In addition, you can get rid of the else, we don't need it, we'll just start off assuming it is prime. If you hit any divisor you know it is not prime:

```
  7     isprime = 1;
  8     for(i = sqrt(x); i > 1; i--)
  9         {
 10             if(x % i == 0)
 11 
 12             /* isprime is false*/
 13                 isprime = 0;
 14                 break;
 15             }
```

Answer (score 0):

prime.c will not do what it is indented to do as because of the else clause the value of isprime depends on the last case checked i.e 2. So if a number is not divisible by 2 it could be falsely labeled as prime. The following code is better.

```
#include<math.h>
int prime(int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=sqrt(x);i>1;--i)
        {
         if(x%i==0)
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
 }
```